# Jenkins CLI empty response

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

Hi I am using the CLI to transfer jobs between two jenkins servers.

But I am unable to get the CLI working..

When I run:
`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <myhost> -auth <myid>:<mysecret> help`

I get a empty response, no errors, no exceptions, just an empty shell prompt

Comment: Are you using ssh ? if yes ? then Did you save your pub key under your profile --> configure --> SSH Public Keys section ?

Comment: I haven't specified the ssh option in the above command line. Do I need ssh keys while using the -auth option as well?

Comment: i still use jenkins 1.X version , that does not support/have -auth option,configuring ssh should be the easy way and when using ssh there is no need for you to use -auth again

Comment: Hi @Vigneshwaren, Did you found a solution for this? My local Jenkins do respond. But the one hosted on a remote server doesnt. Jenkins version 2.XX

Answer (score 1):

If your Jenkins is on Linux and behind an NGINX reverse-proxy server, do the following:

1.Open the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add the following entries:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_buffering off;
```

2.Restart Jenkins and NGINX services:

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

For more details, see [Jenkins behind an NGinX reverse proxy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy).

Answer (score 0):

I get same problem. 
And I find myhost it's nginx address.
I fix it by change myhost to jenkins server